# Do any on hit effects from any champion abilities or items get affected by Spell Vamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always wonder how early I should get a Will of the Ancients over Hextech Revolver. How much it will it affect the rest of my team?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, as the question title seems not to entirely mesh with the question body. If you're asking for a list of abilities/items that are affected by Spell Vamp, it wouldn't be very constructive or viable for us to list a spell for *every* champ, as that would be very unwieldy and quickly go out of date. If you want to compare the effectiveness of WotA vs. Hextech Revolver, that's a different question. Either way, could you please add some information about a specific champion or team build you're thinking of? You'll likely get a better answer then.

Answer (score 13):

So I think that I'm seeing two real questions here:

1. **Do on-hit effects proc spell vamp?**, and
2. **Can items proc spell vamp?**

The first question is a bit of an odd case, because it really depends on what you mean.

**On-Hit Abilities**

Some abilities, such as Gangplank's or Ezreal's <kbd>Q</kbd> are treated exactly like auto-attacks. These trigger on-hit items like Black Cleaver, as well as trigger *Life Steal* and other effects (depending on the champion).

**On-Next-Hit Abilities**

The second kind of attacks are "on-next-hit", which modify the champion's next attack and reset the auto-attack timer. These are abilities like Nasus' Siphoning Strike, Blitzcrank's Power Fist, and Garen's Decisive Strike. These also trigger *Life Steal* and not Spell Vamp.

However, to confuse things, there are also "On-Next-Hit" Abilities that trigger *spell vamp*, such as Poppy's Devastating Blow, and Mordekaiser's Mace of Spades.

[image]

<sub>*Note that Poppy only has spell vamp in this picture. The 15 damage that is visible is from Malady's proc, which was triggered by Devastating Blow.*</sub>

The only difference between the two types of abilities is that one adds a bonus *to* your auto-attack, and the other one *replaces* your auto-attack. The easiest way to test this is to use the ability against a tower. Since towers are (essentially) immune to abilities, if you use it against a tower, and it does *not* consume the charge of the ability, it uses spell vamp. If you *do* manage to deal bonus damage to the tower, it uses life steal.

**Physical Damage Abilities**

Finally, you have some abilities that deal *physical damage*, but are not auto attacks. These are things like Garen's Judgement, or Urgot's Acid Hunter. These things deal physical damage, but, because they are abilities, use *Spell Vamp* instead of Life Steal.

**In general, any given ability onlys benefit from Life Steal *or* Spell Vamp, not both.**

So, should you rush a Will of the Ancients? It depends *entirely* on what champions you have on your team.

**Spell Vamp and Items**

As to your second question, the answer is much simpler: Item's with on-hit damage effects, such as Wit's End, Madred's Razor (and derivatives), or Malady, never proc Spell Vamp.

Deathfire Grasp or Hextech Gunblade, items with direct activations, however, will.

Comment: `if you use it against a tower, and it does not consume the charge of the ability, it uses spell vamp.` Something I knew in the back of my head somewhere but just realised it. Handy quote!

Answer (score 0):

Activated items **are** effected by spell vamp. This includes things like Hextech Gunblade, Deathfire Grasp, and even Smite.

Answer (score 0):

General rules were covered in other answers, though there are some exceptions. Kayle's Righterous Fury (E) is one of those on-hit abilities which do proc spellvamp, for example.

As per LOL Wiki. I have no full list of such exceptions as of yet.